# Subtract min for every column by group - Add Subtracted Values to another column in df

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, dplyr

I have a dataframe below:

```
date    group    col1    col2    col3     col4     col5      
1234        1      -2       3       4       -5      100       
1235        1       4       5      -2       -7      200       
1234        1      -5       2       9        1      400       
1235        1       8       2      -4        7      900       
1235        2     -72      83     -54       98      800      
1233        2      32     -21      -1        4      900      
1342        2     -54       0     -10      -11      100      
1234        2      98      -8      -9      -10      100
```

Here is what I want to do:

For columns df[,3] to the 2nd to last column, I want to do the following:

1) For each column take the minimum value for positive numbers and the minimum number for negative numbers by group.

2) Then replace the current values using this logic:

a) If the value is positive, subtract the minimum value found for the positive numbers by group.

b) If the value is negative, subtract the minimum value found for the negative numbers by group.

c) If the value is 0, make no change

3) Then take the total values that were subtracted for each value in that row and add it to the last column value.

```
Minimum for col1 neg, group 1 = -5
Minimum for col1 pos, group 1 = 4
Minimum for col1 neg, group 2 = -72
Minimum for col1 pos, group 2 = 32
Minimum for col2 neg, group 1 = NA
Minimum for col2 pos, group 1 = 2
etc.
```

I want my final output to look like this:

```
date    group         col1      col2      col3          col4            col5      
1234        1      -2-(-5)       3-2       4-4       -5-(-7)            100+(-5)+2+4+(-7)       
1235        1         4-4        5-2   -2-(-4)       -7-(-7)            200+4+2+(-4)+(-7)      
1234        1      -5-(-5)       2-2       9-4           1-1               400+(-5)+2+4+1       
1235        1         8-4        2-2   -4-(-4)           7-1               900+4+2+(-4)+1       
1235        2    -72-(-72)     83-83 -54-(-54)          98-4         800+(-72)+83+(-54)+4      
1233        2       32-32  -21-(-21)  -1-(-54)           4-4         900+32+(-21)+(-54)+4      
1342        2    -54-(-72)       0-0 -10-(-54)     -11-(-11)      100+(-72)+0+(-54)+(-11)      
1234        2       98-32   -8-(-21)  -9-(-54)     -10-(-11)     100+32+(-21)+(-54)+(-11)
```

Expected Output:

```
date    group         col1      col2      col3          col4            col5      
1234        1            3         1         0             2              94       
1235        1            0         3         2             0             195      
1234        1            0         0         5             0             402       
1235        1            4         0         0             6             903       
1235        2            0         0         0            94             761      
1233        2            0         0        53             0             861      
1342        2           18         0        44             0             -37      
1234        2           66        13        45             1              46
```

Comment: apologies yeah meant to say min only

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Comment: The question is already answered. In my actual dataset there are NA values which might be causing this warning - `In min(col4[col4 < 0]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning -Inf`. Not sure if that is the reason or not based on @akrun's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'group', `mutate` the columns 'col1' to 'col4' with the `min` value of positive and negative numbers, then add the rowwise sum of the numbers with the 'col5' and update 'col5'.  Later, update the 'col1' to 'col4' by subtracting from the corresponding columns of initial dataset ('df1')

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate_at(3:6, 
   funs(case_when(. < 0  ~ if(any(. < 0)) as.numeric(min(.[. <0])) else NA_real_,
              . > 0 ~ if(any(. > 0)) as.numeric(min(.[. > 0])) else NA_real_, 
                           TRUE ~ as.numeric(.)))) %>%
   ungroup %>%                        
   mutate(col5 = col5 + rowSums(.[3:6])) 

nm1 <- paste0("col", 1:4)
#nm1 <- 3:6
df2[nm1] <- df1[nm1] - df2[nm1]
df2
# A tibble: 8 x 7
#   date group  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
#  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1234     1     3     1     0     2    94
#2  1235     1     0     3     2     0   195
#3  1234     1     0     0     5     0   402
#4  1235     1     4     0     0     6   903
#5  1235     2     0     0     0    94   761
#6  1233     2     0     0    53     0   861
#7  1342     2    18     0    44     0   -37
#8  1234     2    66    13    45     1    46
```

---

Or using a modification with `parse_exprs`

```
library(rlang)
expr <- paste(glue::glue('{nm1} - {nm1}_new'), collapse=";")
df1 %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate_at(3:6, funs(new = ave(., sign(.), FUN = min))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(col5 = col5 + select(., col1_new:col4_new)  %>% 
                    reduce(`+`)) %>% 
   transmute(date, group, !!! parse_exprs(expr), col5) %>%
   rename_at(3:6, ~ nm1)
# A tibble: 8 x 7
#   date group  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1  1234     1     3     1     0     2    94
#2  1235     1     0     3     2     0   195
#3  1234     1     0     0     5     0   402
#4  1235     1     4     0     0     6   903
#5  1235     2     0     0     0    94   761
#6  1233     2     0     0    53     0   861
#7  1342     2    18     0    44     0   -37
#8  1234     2    66    13    45     1    46
```

---

Or convert to 'long' format to do the calculations and then change it to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
  gather(key, val, col1:col4) %>%
  group_by(group, key, sn= sign(val)) %>% 
  mutate(mnVal = min(val)) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  mutate(col5 = col5 + sum(mnVal), val = val - mnVal) %>% 
  select(-sn, -mnVal) %>%
  spread(key, val) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  select(names(df1))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c(1234L, 1235L, 1234L, 1235L, 1235L, 1233L, 
1342L, 1234L), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), col1 = c(-2L, 
4L, -5L, 8L, -72L, 32L, -54L, 98L), col2 = c(3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
83L, -21L, 0L, -8L), col3 = c(4L, -2L, 9L, -4L, -54L, -1L, -10L, 
-9L), col4 = c(-5L, -7L, 1L, 7L, 98L, 4L, -11L, -10L), col5 = c(100L, 
200L, 400L, 900L, 800L, 900L, 100L, 100L)), .Names = c("date", 
"group", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```